# How to create a page that leads to multiple scrollviews in swift

Tags: xcode, swift

The beginning page is a table view. On the table view there is table that contains four different topics(picture provided). I would like each topic to lead to a new page that is a scroll view. I have successfully programmed so that the first topic will lead to a scroll view. However, I am having trouble creating more than one scroll view page for each topic. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoBPN.png)

Comment: Why don't you just have the destination page be the target for all the topics and modify it as necessary?

Answer (score 0):

#### How to:

1. Create destination view controllers in your storyboard.
2. Create segues by CTRL-dragging from cell to the view controller that should be shown when the cell is tapped.